# Unity3d too many clones

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I m trying to make 10 candies on center of road. Instead 10 its making 77 with the tag. I changed the condition can't fix it still. func is called on update

```
void CloneCandyCenter() {
     if(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("r1candycenter").Length  < 2) {
        Debug.Log("0 candies now adding 10 more");
       
        for(int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
     Instantiate(R1candyCenter, new Vector3(0,0, CandyZpos.z), transform.rotation, Road1Trans);        
        CandyZpos.z += 2;
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show how are you calling `CloneCandyCenter`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/25lcsxq

Comment: ah, you said in the question

Comment: I think I wrote the condition wrong. if the condition from if is true 2 times then for will make 20 clones. the first games is the hardest

Comment: but if the `R1CandyCenter` gamebject has got the tag, in the second call there should be 10 already, so you should only have the first 10

Comment: I did what you told me. the problem was in my road script. i was making clones of road which is parent of the candies. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont call  `CloneCandyCenter` in the apdate, as this is being called 60 times per second approx.

Call it in the `Start()` for example to be called once, or upon key press.

```
If (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyKode.Space))
    CloneCandyCenter();
```

However if the R1CandyCenter gamebject has got the tag, in the second call there should be 10 already, so you should only have the first 10, so apart from the inneficiency of `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` being called in an update which is not recommended, your code should be working fine regarding the number of abjects created.

I suggest to use a counter:

```
int candyCenterCounter = 0; //class variable
void CloneCandyCenter() {
     if(candyCenterCounter < 2) { //2 would not make sense if objects are instantiated 10 by 10
        Debug.Log("0 candies now adding 10 more");

     for(int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
         Instantiate(R1candyCenter, new Vector3(0,0, CandyZpos.z), 
         transform.rotation, Road1Trans);        
         CandyZpos.z += 2;
     }
     candyCenterCounter+=10 
}
```